# R barplot dimensions dependent on number of bars/bar size

Tags: r

I am trying to produce many barplots and would to keep the bar size fixed and have the plot dimensions change based on the barplot size. The default in R seems to create bars that fill the view port evenly.

Is there a wayto specify a constant bar width and have the final dimensions of the plot based on that? In the examples below, I would like the second plot to have the same bar width as the first.

When producing many plots with varying bar-sizes, they quickly begin to look ugly.

Please ignore the axis text, these are rough plots.

## Example with many bars

[image: Example with many bars]

## Example with only two bars:

[image: Example with only two bars]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the space option int the barplot.
Also you can use the option of width and xlim together to format your bars